# How to find spin axis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-spin

Suppose we have some spin state, defined using $z$ axis, say
$$
|\psi\rangle=|z;\downarrow\rangle + |z;\uparrow\rangle.
$$
How to find axis at which this spin state points?

PS: This is not a homework question. Interested in general solution.

Comment: As written your state is not normalized...  not that it affects the answer but still...

Answer (score 3):

If your $\vert\psi\rangle$ points along an axis, it will be an eigenstate of
$\hat S=\hat n\cdot \vec \sigma=n_x\sigma_x+n_y\sigma_y+n_z\sigma_z$ with $\hat n$ pointing along this axis.  (Do you see why?)

Thus, the simplest approach is to write the general form of $\hat S$, find the eigenvectors of this $\hat S$, and solve for the components of $\hat n$ by comparing with your $\vert\psi\rangle$.

Comment: Instead of solving the eigenvalue problem in generality, one could also  calculate $\hat{S} |\psi\rangle$ for a general $\hat{S}$ and then find for which values of $n_x$, $n_y$, and $n_z$ we have $\hat{S} |\psi\rangle =  |\psi\rangle$.  (Solving the general eigenvalue problem is a valuable exercise and worth doing at least once in your career, but my method is probably less complicated.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a state
$$|\psi\rangle = a|\uparrow\rangle +b |\downarrow \rangle $$

Then first rotate the state around $z-$axis with
$$U_z=\exp(-i \frac{\sigma_z}{2} \phi)$$

Choose $\phi$ such that the ratio between resulting spin-up and spin-down amplitudes is real (i.e. to bring the spin into the $x-z$ plane). You will find the polar angle of the original orientation this way.

Then rotate around $y-$axis:
$$U_y=\exp(-i \frac{\sigma_y}{2}\theta)$$
until the spin is looking completely up; $\theta$ is your azimuthal angle.

Answer (score 0):

There is a key concept, known as the [Bloch sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere), which basically solves this in one go.

In essence, if you have an arbitrary superposition of two states, $|{↑}⟩$ and $|{↓}⟩$, once you normalize and you remove an arbitrary global phase, the state can always be written in the form
$$
|\psi⟩ = \cos(\theta/2) |{↑}⟩ + e^{i\phi} \sin(\theta/2)|{↓}⟩,
$$
where $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ and $\phi\in[0,2\pi)$.

The core result is a theorem that states that this state is an eigenstate of the spin component operator $\hat{n}\cdot\hat{\mathbf S}$ along the direction with unit vector $\hat{n}$, where $(\theta,\phi)$ are the spherical coordinates of $\hat{n}$.

To see that this is the case, you first start with an explicit expression for the spin component operator in terms of the Pauli matrices,
\begin{align}
\hat{n}\cdot\hat{\mathbf S}
& =
\frac{\hbar}{2}\hat{n}\cdot\hat{\boldsymbol\sigma}
\\ & =
\frac\hbar2 \left[ n_x \sigma_x + n_y \sigma_y + n_z \sigma_z \right]
\\ & =
\frac\hbar2 \left[ 
\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi) \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}
+\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi) \begin{pmatrix}0&-i\\i&0\end{pmatrix}
+\cos(\theta)\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}
\right]
\\ & =
\frac\hbar2 
\begin{pmatrix} \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta)e^{-i\phi} \\ \sin(\theta)e^{i\phi} & -\cos(\theta) \end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
and then it is a simple application of the sum-angle trigonometric identities to verify that $|\psi⟩$ is an eigenvector of this matrix.

This is, of course, only the start of the deep connection involved (which is particularly strong if you have mixed states, described by density matrices). For more details see Wikipedia, or an introductory textbook on quantum information such as Nielsen & Chuang.